# why is homebrew needed a permission of /usr/local/share/man/man8

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I installed `python3` using **brew**, brew returned an error message which said I don't have `permission of /usr/local/share/man/man8`.

I want to know about why is **brew** needed the `permissions`.

Somebody tell me...

[image: brew install python3]

Comment: 'Cause it wants to install manuals…?

Comment: ah ha...
Then, can I install a program without man page using brew?